# where to get build file to deploy to server

Tags: circleci

I've set up config to tell circle ci what to build and how to build.

After the the build I want to send all the built files to my ftp server, which is a share host (host-gator)

Can I instruct circleCI to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two separate things here. If the build files that you want to upload are your application itself, then this is considered a deploy. You can do this in the `deployment` phase in `circle.yml`. More info can be found here: https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/#deployment

If the build is "other" files that you want to upload for record keeping, debugging, or basically a deployment for someday in the future, you can utilize what are called build artifacts: https://circleci.com/docs/build-artifacts/